# JqGrid - search using subgrid columns and rebuild main grid

Tags: mongodb, search, jqgrid

I have a main grid with related data in subgrid. I'd like to know if there is a way to either populate the main grid search (perhaps using a template?) with the columns from the subgrid, or use a search from the subgrid to repopulate the main grid based upon the subgrid search.

To explain: I have a MongoDB full of image records and each image record has a specimen sub document. I display the image information in the main jqGrid, and the specimen information in a subgrid. I'd like to be able to perform a search on the main jqGrid columns (which I'm able to do now), as well as perform a search using the specimen columns. Performing a search on the specimen columns will return those image records with similar data, repopulating the main grid.

I know how to handle the back end part. Just need to know how to enable this in jqGrid. I should mention, colModel and colNames are handled dynamically. Templates? An event I can trigger in the subgrid search that is then passed to the main grid search? A way to populating the main grid search with subgrid columns?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out from other posts. In the subgrid, I use the onSearch function to populate the postData and then reload the main grid.

```
onSearch: function(){
  $("#jqGridExplore").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    search: true,
    postData: { "filters" : $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters, "subgrid" : true }
  }).trigger("reloadGrid");

  return false;
}
```

I return false so the subgrid url is not called and add a subgrid = true parameter to the url string for handling on the back end.